# Pytest with Selenium Grid does not find element but with 'local' selenium it does

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, selenium-grid

I use PyTest and Selenium Hub. For some reason selenium can not find the H1 on a page.

**Docker selenium grid**

- image: selenium/hub:3.8.1-dubnium
- selenium/node-chrome:3.8.1-dubnium

I have 2 drivers (for testing purposes).

**Selenium Grid**

```
desired_capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome', 'javascriptEnabled': True}  
remote_driver = 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub'
chrome_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=remote_driver, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
request.cls.driver = chrome_driver
```

**Local driver**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_driver)
```

If i do this:
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1'))).text

**Scenario**

Using google.com:

- Local driver --> finds H1
- Remote drviver --> finds H1

Using mydomain.com

- Local driver --> finds H1
- Remote drviver --> does not find H1 (but it does find the 'title' tag via driver.title)

I would say my the DOM is not rendered when i test my site. The local driver (that pops up a window) does render it and finds the h1.

How should i adjust the remote driver in a way it also finds the 1?

Comment: Are you trying to access your site via localhost url like `driver.get('http://localhost:8080/')`?

Comment: No full url, like https://www.example.com. There seems to be no issue regarding reaching the docker image. Since other tests are going smooth, but none use the DOM. They are around getting status codes.

Comment: You might `print(driver.page_source)` to see the content on the page and to compare the local and remote output. Maybe this will add more details about what happened.